# Bash multi input Java tester

Tags: java, linux, bash, unix

I am currently trying to make a bash testing script that will...

1) Go into many peoples folders

2) Compile their two java files

3) Run two quick tests for the the compiled results and send the output to a file to be saved in their folder

4) Take the results of those four result files, and dump them into one result file with a template at the top for me to input the results

... and I currently have most of this done. My only issue is that their program asks for a couple lines of input, for example...

Input num 1:

Input num 2:

Input num 3:

... and so on, and I am not sure how to get it to continue putting input into their program. Do I need an EOF after my hard coded input in my bash file?? Here is what I have so far...

```
#! /bin/bash


for i in $(find . -maxdepth 1 -type d)
do

    pwd
    pushd "$i"
    pwd

    if [ -f "First.java" ];
    then
        javac -cp . First.java
        echo easyFirst.txt | java -cp . First - > easyFirstResult
        echo hardFirst.txt | java -cp . First - > hardFirstResult
    fi

    if [ -f "Second.java" ];
    then
        javac -cp . Second.java
        echo easySecond | java -cp . Second - > easySecondResult
        echo hardSecond | java -cp . Second - > hardSecondResult
    fi


    printf "easyFirstResult\t: \hardFirstResult\t: \easySecondResult\t: \hardSecondResult\t: " > lab5grade.txt

    popd

done
```

P.S. Everything is working besides the multi-line input, and I have two text files with my hard coded input to test the code.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you think about using a tool like [Apache Ant](http://ant.apache.org/) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org/)? They can help a lot once your project gets more complex. (Although Maven itself can cause you to get grey hair...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see commands like

```
echo easyFirst.txt | java -cp . First - > easyFirstResult
```

apparently supplying a line of input to the java programs; but `echo` commands like that don't transfer file contents, they merely copy text like "easyFirst.txt" to stdout.  To pipe the contents of file easyFirst.txt into First, use a command like

```
java -cp . First - < easyFirst.txt > easyFirstResult
```

(Note, the above supposes classpath is `.`, class is `First`, and `-` is an unexplained command line argument to First.)

Comment: Okay. Yes I the classpath is ., and I do check to guarantee First and Second are the class names.

Comment: My question now I guess is, how do I need to format my txt file to ensure that one line will be the response to their programs first request for input and "hit enter", then move on to my next line and continue to do the same thing until the end of my txt file.

Comment: I believe one item per line should do it.  I'm short of time at the moment and can't test, sorry.